# Proof of upper semi-continuity of sheaf cohomology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Spec}{Spec}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{im}$
Hello Math.Stackexchange.com-Community.

*Sorry for asking two questions at the same time, however they are part of one single step in a proof and hence closely related.*
*My questions arise from the following context:*

Let $X\to Y$ be a proper morphism between locally noetherian Schemes and let $\mathcal{F}$ be a coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-module on $X$ which is flat over $\mathcal{O}_Y$.
Then for all $p\geq 0$ the function $h^p(-,\mathcal{F})\colon Y\to\mathbb{N}$ which is defined by 
$h^p(y,\mathcal{F}):=\dim_{\kappa(y)}H^p(X_y,\mathcal{F}|_{X_y})$
is upper semi-continuous in the sense that for all $c\in\mathbb{R}$ the set $\{y\in Y\mid h^p(y,\mathcal{F})\leq c\}$ is open.

*In order to prove this, the following lemma was invoked:*

**Lemma:**
Let $A$ be a noetherian ring.
Let $\delta\colon M\to F$ be a morphism between finitely-generated $A$-modules, of which $F$ is free.
Then, the function $g\colon \Spec(A)\to \mathbb{N}$ defined by 
$g(\mathfrak{p}):=\dim_{\kappa(\mathfrak{p})}(\ker(M\otimes_A \kappa(\mathfrak{p})\overset{\delta_{\mathfrak{p}}:=\delta\otimes_A \kappa(\mathfrak{p})}{\to} F\otimes_A \kappa(\mathfrak{p}))$ is upper semi-continuous.

*My question arises in the proof of this lemma, which goes as follows:*

**Proof**
Let $\mu_1,\cdots,\mu_s\in M$ be elements, such that the images $\overline{\mu_1},\cdots,\overline{\mu_s}\in M\otimes_A\kappa(\mathfrak{p})$ form a basis of that vector space, and such that $\delta_{\mathfrak{p}}(\overline{\mu_i})$ vanish for $i=1,\cdots,r=g(\mathfrak{p})$ and form a basis of $\im(\delta_{\mathfrak{p}})$ for $i=r+1,\cdots,s$.

*Here comes the part that I don't understand, and also my first question:*

Since the assertion is local near any $\mathfrak{p}$ we may replace $A$ by $A_f$ for $f\not \in\mathfrak{p}$ and assume that $M$ is generated by the $\mu_1,\cdots\mu_s$ as an $A$ module.

The last assertion is clear to me. This is a Nakayama-Style argument.
It is however not clear to me, what "local near $\mathfrak{p}$" means, and why this implies, that we may replace $A$ by $A_f$. Aside from this argument, it is also not clear to me, how to prove by hand (i.e. without using the "near $\mathfrak{p}$"-Argument) why we may replace $A$ by $A_f$.

*I tried and failed as follows:*
Assume that we may find a covering by $D(f_j)$'s of $\Spec(A)$ such that the morphisms $g_j\colon Spec(A_{f_j})\to\mathbb{N}, g_j(\mathfrak{p}_j)=\dim_{\kappa(\mathfrak{p}_j)}(\ker(M_{f_j}\otimes_{A_{f_j}}\kappa(\mathfrak{p}_{f_j})\to F_{f_j}\otimes_{A_{f_j}}\kappa(\mathfrak{p}_{f_j}))$ is EDIT: <strike>locally constant</strike> upper semi-continuous, where by $\mathfrak{p}_j$ I mean the prime ideal in $\Spec(A_{f_j})$ corresponding to $\mathfrak{p}\in D(f_j)$.

Then it would suffice if one could show that this implies, that the restrictions of $g$ to the $D(f_j)$ are upper semi-continuous.

In order to show this one would have to show, that for every $c\in\mathbb{R}$ we have $\dim_{\kappa(\mathfrak{p}_j)}(\ker(M_{f_j}\otimes_{A_{f_j}}\kappa(\mathfrak{p}_{f_j})\to F_{f_j}\otimes_{A_{f_j}}\kappa(\mathfrak{p}_{f_j}))\leq c$ for all $j$ iff $\dim_{\kappa(\mathfrak{p})}(\ker(M\otimes_A \kappa(\mathfrak{p})\overset{\delta\otimes_A \kappa(\mathfrak{p})}{\to} F\otimes_A \kappa(\mathfrak{p}))\leq c$ for all prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}\in D(f_j)$.

This is the point where I don't see how to continue.

*My second question is why we may construct a basis for $M_{f_j}\otimes_{A_{f_j}}\kappa(\mathfrak{p_{f_j}})$* out of the basis for $M\otimes_A \kappa(\mathfrak{p})$ such that it still has the properties we set up in the beginning of the proof, so that we may carry on with the proof after replacing $A$ by $A_f$.

Thank You for your participation!

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer your first question. I will use the following setup:
$A$ a noetherian ring, $M$ a finitely generated $A$-module, and $p$ a prime ideal of $A$. We show that if $M_p$ is generated by the images of $x_1,\dots, x_n \in M$, then there exists $f \in A$ such that $M_f$ is generated by the images of the same set of elements.

Let $N$ be the $A$-submodule of $M$ generated by $x_1,\dots, x_n$, and let $K$ be the cokernel of the inclusion map $N \to M$. 
Our goal is to find an element $f \in A$ such that $K_f = 0$.
If $K$ is $0$, then there is nothing to do. Assume that $K \neq 0$. 
Consider the support of $K$. Since $K$ is finitely generated $Supp(K)$ is determined by an $A$-ideal $I$, and since $p$ is not in it, $I$ is a proper ideal. Hence we may choose any nonzero element in $I$ for $f$.

Comment: Hello. Thank You for the answer. However I don't see how this answers any of my questions. My first question was, what "local near $\mathfrak{p}$" means, and how it implies that we may replace $A$ by $A_f$.  Could You clarify in a little more detail, how exactly this fact from Commutative Algebra answers my question?

Comment: $\DeclareMathOperator{\Ann}{Ann}$ $\DeclareMathOperator{\Supp}{Supp}$ Furthermore, what means "determined by"? I know, that if $M$ is a finitely generated $A$-module then $\Supp(M)=V(\Ann(M))$, but if I take any nonzero element $f\in \Ann(M)=I$ then $M_f=0$, since $\frac{m}{f^k}=\frac{fm}{f^{k+1}}=0$.

Comment: Your argument in the 2nd comment is correct. Since we want $N_f = M_f$, it is equivalent to $(M/N)_f = 0$ (in my post, I used $L$ for $M/N$). For your first comment, $p$ is in $Spec A - V(I)$, hence $p$ is in $D(f) = Spec A - V(f)$.

Comment: $\DeclareMathOperator{\Supp}{Supp}\DeclareMathOperator{\Spec}{Spec}\DeclareMathOperator{\Ann}{Ann}$Ok. My doubt in the second comment is clear now, I just confused $K$ with $M$. However I still don't see which of my questions You are answering and how. I have no doubts about $\mathfrak{p}\in\Spec(A)\setminus V(I)$ (what is$ I$? Do, You mean $I=\Ann(M)$?) $\implies \mathfrak{p}\in D(f)$, but which of my question does this answer and how? If you mean $I=\Ann(M)$, then $\mathfrak{p}\in\Spec(A)\setminus V(I) \implies M_{\mathfrak{p}}=0$ by definition of $\Supp(−)$

Comment: $\DeclareMathOperator{\Spec}{Spec}$I think your argument only shows that we may - after localization - assume that $M$ is generated by the $\mu_1,\cdots,\mu_s$, but that was already clear to me (as I pointed out) by another (somewhat different ) Nakayama-style argument. What really concerns me are the other questions, for instance, why is the construction of the map $g$ compatible with $\Spec(A_f)\cong D(f)$.

Comment: This is a priori not obvious. It is clear, that if the restrictions of a map to some covering are upper semi-continuous, then the whole map is, but the fact that replacing $A$ by $A_f$ and $M$ by $M_f$ in the definition of $g$ gives $g|_{D(f)}$ needs a proof.